# Ajuda com url amigavel

Tags: php, htaccess

Não tenho conhecimento nenhum de programação, no entanto me atrevi a desenvolver um site e estou com problemas pra que a url mostrada no browser apareça de forma amigável e gostaria da ajuda dos nobres programadores.
As regras do meu .htaccess estão da seguinte maneira:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)\/?$ proprietario.php?$1nome=$2 [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)\/?$ imovel.php?onde=$1&numero=$2 [NC,L]
```

Tenho dois arquivos que fazem um Select no meu banco, um deles sendo o imovel.php e o proprietario.php. Todos os esses meus arquivos estão na pasta public.html incluindo também o .htaccess e meu index.php que faz o envio através do método GET.
Minha index possui formulários de pesquisa. Ou seja, o que é digitado no formulário será o conteúdo da url com o formato "amigável".
Gostaria que a exibição da url no browser fosse algo do tipo http://www.meusite.com/proprietario/a10-participacoes-eireli mas mesmo tentando várias regras com o .htaccess o resultado sempre é http://www.meusite.com/proprietario.php?nome=a10+participacoes+eireli.
O outro caso sempre exibe algo do tipo http://www.meusite.com/imovel.php?onde=01311-000&numero=1000 quando eu gostaria que fosse exibido http://www.meusite.com/imovel/01311-000/1000. Para este caso no lugar de 01311-000 que é recebido formulário de pesquisa poderia ser palavras ao invés de números e gostaria que fosse exibido da seguinte maneira http://www.meusite.com/imovel/av-paulista/1000

Comment: Usou algum CMS (Sistema Gestor de Conteúdos) para desenvolver esse site? Se sim qual?

Comment: Não usei. Apenas criei os arquivos em php e os coloquei na pasta public. Existem algumas outras pastas de imagens e css que estão organizadas dentro da public também

Comment: Se o link acima não resolver, tem **[muitas outras postagens no site sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bphp%5d%20url%20amig%c3%a1vel)**

Comment: Bacco, acredite, já vasculhei bastante e não consegui uma resposta pro meu problema que aparentemente é simples. No entanto não consegui solução.

Comment: Procure mais um pouco, posso afirmar com muita tranquilidade que o que tem para falar de URL amigável com PHP já foi mais do que esgotado aqui no site. Não há nada mais que possa ser respondido que não tenha sido falado aqui antes. Se DEPOIS de implementar tiver algum problema que é único para o seu caso, aí basta fazer uma pergunta específica com seu código, e descrever exatamente a parte que não deu certo, aí talvez caiba uma resposta específica para sua situação. Do que foi postado atualmente na sua pergunta, tem tudo já.

Comment: Lembre-se que você pode [edit] a postagem a qualquer momento, se quiser ser mais específico e focar em detalhes que atualmente não constam no post. Se realmente depois da edição não houver postagem que tenha o caminho para a solução, obviamente que a comunidade pode reabrir (lembrando que são 229 resultados apenas para a pesquisa que eu fiz, que foi até um pouco restritiva demais - tentando outros termos, talvez ache coisas até mais específicas).

Comment: Uma dica que talvez possa ajudar no seu caso específico na busca (e que também tem no site, só estou repetindo pra tentar ajudar) é que você provavelmente vai fazer um redirect, por exemplo aponta seu form para "pesquisar.php" que redireciona para "/busca/palavra1-palavra2-palavra3" para evitar ter que usar JS no formulário. Provavelmente sua dificuldade está no fato do GET passar a URL sempre do jeito normal ?parametros, mas ai o PHP não pode interceptar. Para isso o redirect, que fica transparente para o usuário final.

Comment: Essa aqui tem a ver com o que eu comentei faz pouco: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=.htaccess+query+string - não que não possa ser feito por .htaccess, mas acho que com PHP vai facilitar sua vida.

Comment: Ok. Vou rever alguns assuntos novamente incluindo sua sugestão. Posso ter deixado passar algo despercebido.  Obrigado

Comment: Pense nessa do redirect, ou busque por um .htaccess que seja específico pra query string, qq coisa comente aqui. estou dando mais uma espiada se acho alguma mais específica também. Dependendo como for, podemos pensar na revisão do seu texto pra focar nesse ponto específico da busca, para pensarmos em reabertura.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode ajudar é simplificar o texto, mais no formato "o que tentou" e "o que aconteceu em vez do que esperava", pra não cair daquela do "façam pra mim", que realmente acaba não dando muito certo. Talvez um pouco mais de detalhes dos critérios do seu form (pq um deles vai para /imovel mas o outro vai pra /proprietario? são forms diferentes, vai ter que pegar do select, ou o que? quais são os campos do form, se for esse ultimo caso - o select é que determina o primeiro lugar depois da barra?). São exemplos, claro.